# Silent install msi from a windows service local service account

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-installer, silent-installer

I am building an auto-updating mechanism. A windows service that runs on a local service account responsible with the auto-updating of a msi.

The service downloads the msi file then it tries to install it using this code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" /i \"{0}\" /qn /norestart ALLUSERS=1", sMSIPath);
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Where sMSIPath is a string representing the path to the file, for example "C:\test.msi".

This code, from a regular console application seems to be running fine. I managed to silently install adobe reader, for example.

But from my windows service, it does nothing. According to the logs, i get a warning with this message:
Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80070005
Where the user is "LOCAL SERVICE" (as i mentioned, my windows service runs as a local service).

Also, the projects have target x86, but i am running a 64-bit OS. (i need them at x86, i want this software to be able to run on multiple operating systems).

Any help is very well received.
Thanks alot!

Comment: You want local system, not local service.  The latter is a non-administrative context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have much chance of making this work. If the MSI tries to access folders like Desktop, User's Program Menu, the CommonFilesFolder (not a complete list) or looks at the LogonUser property and any number of other things it will fail because in a normal install from the interactive user these are all valid properties associated with that installing user. When the installing user is localservice you're likely to be in a mess.

If you need to do this, configure the service to run as a valid administrator account - that might give you a chance of it working better. It's possible that the failure to connect to server error is because MSI files are expected to be run from some kind of user account.

Comment: Installation usually (though not always) works fine using Local System.  But Local Service doesn't have much of a chance; on top of all the issues you mention, it doesn't have sufficient privilege.  (Local Service is a *non-administrative* context.)

Comment: Good point - I'd forgotten about localservice's restricted privileges.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open service management console Start->Run->Services.msc
2. Right click on your service and go to properties
3. On property page select second tab i.e. "Log On"
4. Check checkbox called "Allow Service to interact with desktop".

Comment: Deprecated as of Windows Vista.  (It does still have some effect on the security context of the process, but it is unlikely to be helpful in this case.)

Comment: @Harry: I was not aware of that. For my knowledge purpose could you please point me to link where I can find details regarding deprecation of interactive mode? I searched but couldn't find any official link on msdn except on some non-ms forums.

Comment: The key phrase is "session 0 isolation", see in particular http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb203962(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx