# Windows Service running as a specific user (not Local System) cannot use msiexec

Tags: windows, process, windows-services, windows-installer, createprocess

I am creating a Windows Service in C++.

I want to allow the Windows Service to update itself (upon a certain trigger) by running `msiexec /p patch.msp /quiet /qn`.

I am currently using the Windows function [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to achieve this, and it works correctly *as long as the service is running as Local System*. The service creates a new process which executes the `msiexec` command, and the service is updated correctly. However, I require the service to run as another user, not Local System. I have configured `Log On As` user for the service, and granted the user the necessary permissions for the service to do its tasks. Everything about the service works when running as the other user, *except this msiexec command*.

Although the service successfully issues the `msiexec` command, the actual installation is failing with the following msi log:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 2/13/2024  17:11:03  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:661]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:661]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:661]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {*******}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:663]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:663]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:671]: Failed to connect to server. Error: 0x80070005

MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:673]: Note: 1: 2774 2: 0x80070005 
1: 2774 2: 0x80070005 
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:674]: Failed to connect to server.
MSI (c) (E8:64) [17:11:03:674]: MainEngineThread is returning 1601
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2/13/2024  17:11:03 ===
```

I have tried these other scenarios, which work fine:

- Opening a cmd prompt as the user and running the service exe from that console (not as a service) results in the `msiexec` command working correctly!
- Adding the user to the Administrators group allows the service to issue the `msiexec`command correctly!

I have researched the issue--I know 0x80070005 is an "Access denied" code without further explanation. I have found these issues:

- [What's stopping my windows service from running an MSI installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647643/whats-stopping-my-windows-service-from-running-an-msi-installer) Administrative installation is not applicable, I don't think.
- [Windows service calling msiexec does not update the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526178/windows-service-calling-msiexec-does-not-update-the-service)
  *[Silent install msi from a windows service local service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985789/silent-install-msi-from-a-windows-service-local-service-account)

None of these answer my question exactly, though they come close. It seems like it may be a problem that the service is creating a process that is not interactive, or in session 0, and that these might interfere with `msiexec`.

- Is there a permission or user right or group I can add to my service's user that will allow `msiexec` to run correctly? (besides adding the user to Admin)
- Is there some parameter in `CreateProcessW` and adjacent functions that might be required, maybe?
- If it's not possible using this method, why? The above posts reference session 0 and interactivity, but the service works correctly when the user is an Admin, while the service is still running in session 0 and and without interactivity. Any explanation or intuition about any of this is welcome.
- Any other ideas for achieving my goal with other methods?

Comment: can only say that `IMsiServer * CreateMsiServerProxy()` inside msi.dll is fail. it basically call `CoCreateInstance` for `IMsiServer` with `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`. if it ok - the `msiexec.exe /V` process started as service. but in your case `CoCreateInstance` fail with access denied. it be good look under debugger internal, why

Comment: And *Adding the user to the Administrators group allows the service to issue the msiexeccommand correctly!* This is explained all. For have permission start msi service you need be or admin or interactive. In case your user not admin and not run interactive you got access denied

Comment: despite the 'NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE' have the same permissions as 'NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE' and your user have 'NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE'..

Comment: @RbMm Thank you! For my own education, do you have a source link for this: "For have permission start msi service you need be or admin or interactive"

Comment: i check com call `RPC_INTERFACE::DoSecurityCallbackHelper -> ORPCInterfaceSecCallback -> CheckAccess -> CallAccessCheck -> AccessCheckByType` and caller checked with next SD - `O:BAD:(A;OICI;CC;;;IU)(A;OICI;CC;;;SY)(A;OICI;CC;;;BA)(A;OICI;CC;;;LS)(A;OICI;CC;;;NS)` this mean `NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE` , `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, `BUILTIN\Administrators`, `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`, `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` only have access. and you not have because not interactive or admin. (prev sd was for service itself, not com interface which additional check do)

Comment: Thank you very much @RbMm ! I consider the question solved. I will have to find another way to accomplish this service upgrade.